# Отображение картинки по частям

Tags: javascript, изображения

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <body>
   <div id="slideshow">
     <img width="512px" height="384px" src="1.gif" usemap="#slideshowMap">
    <img width="512" height="384" src="2.gif">
  <img width="512" height="384" src="3.gif">
     <map name="slideshowMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 63, 47">
   <area shape="rect" coords="64, 48, 127, 95">
  <area shape="rect" coords="128, 96, 191, 143">
  <area shape="rect" coords="192, 144, 255, 191">
  <area shape="rect" coords="256, 192, 319, 239">
 <area shape="rect" coords="320, 240, 383, 287">
 <area shape="rect" coords="384, 288, 447, 335">
  <area shape="rect" coords="448, 336, 511, 383">
 </map>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

У картинок установлен `display none` (пробовал также `visibility hidden`). Мне нужно, чтобы по очереди появлялись все `area`. Пробовал указывать им `display: block` или `visibility: visible`, но они не отображаются.

Как сделать, чтобы можно было отображать изображение по кусочкам? Хочу сделать смену картинок как на этом сайте http://ww2.ru. Какие есть способы с помощью *javascript* и *css*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не мучайтесь. Всё уже написано: [COIN SLIDER (jQuery Image Slider with Unique Effects)](http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/)

Comment: А не подскажете, как свое реализовать ? Хотелось бы знать как оно работает, а исходник там очень большой.

Comment: они отображают картинку много раз, используя css background-image: и background-position: . лучше сделать на canvas, хоть и не столь кроссбраузерно, зато можно действительно крутые эффекты делать.

Comment: А где можно почитать про canvas для чайников ?

Comment: [Обучение canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_canvas)